# Line break character while looping through an array/function

Tags: javascript, jquery, line-breaks

Seemingly simple but I can't find the correct placement.  I have the following function in my HTML head:

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $.fn.writeText = function(content) {
        var contentArray = content,
            current = 0,
            elem = this;
        setInterval(function() {
            if(current < contentArray.length) {
                elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);                
            }
        }, 1000);
    };    
})(jQuery); 
</script>
```

I call it in the body like:

```
<script>
// test getArray() method in external JS file
document.write(getArray());
$(document).ready(function($){      
    var contentArray = getArray();
    $('#calculations').writeText(contentArray);
}); 
</script>
<h3>Fibonacci Sequence:</h3>
<p id='calculations'></p>
```

I can't find out where to place the '+ br /' to concatenate each writeText with a line break.

Comment: Not sure I get it, jQuery's `text()` replaces the content, it does not add lines, is that the issue you're having ?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I am certain that how you are doing it is way more complicated than necessary. Could you please describe what you want the expected behavior to be?

Comment: @adeneo I'm taking an array and displaying each element of the array on a timed interval on a new line.  I have a function that cycles through the array displaying each array element on the same line but I can't figure out where to put the line break to accomplish my overall goal.

Comment: @protonfish  I'm taking an array and displaying each element of the array on a timed interval on a new line. I have a function that cycles through the array displaying each array element on the same line but I can't figure out where to put the line break to accomplish my overall goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using line breaks is a little amateur. Here's a script that appends paragraph tags.

```
$(function() {      
    var contentArray = ['first', 'second', 'third'],
        iContent = 0;

    function showContent() {
        $('#calculations').append('<p>' + contentArray[iContent] + '</p>');
        if (iContent < contentArray.length - 1) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {showContent(); }, 1000);
            iContent = iContent + 1;
        }
    }

    window.setTimeout(function () {showContent(); }, 1000);
});
```

Also you don't need

```
$(document).ready(
```

A simple $( will do the same. Why are you doing a document.write() in your code? If you just want to see the array values a console.log() would work better.

Comment: The write() was a test to verify the array being pulled from my external JS file.  As I'm sure you can tell, being new to JS, I was trying to step through the code to check for breakpoints like I would have done in VS for .NET projects.  I'll note the cosole.log() for future reference, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a wild stab at what I think you are trying to do, but if I am correct, wouldn't this work?

```
$('#calculations').html(getArray().join('<br>'));
```

I would also not put JS in the head of your doc. Put it at the end the the body tag instead.